# left join in TransactSQL returning me unexpected result - is my understanding for left join wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my data

```
CREATE TABLE TempA (  
  ID  INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
  Msg  VARCHAR(20)  
)  

INSERT INTO TempA (Msg) values ( 'a')  
INSERT INTO TempA (Msg) values ( 'b')  
INSERT INTO TempA (Msg) values ( 'c')  

CREATE TABLE TempB (  
  ID  INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
  Msg  VARCHAR(20)  
)
```

So TempB is empty. Now I run following query

```
   select a.* 
     from TempA a 
left JOIN TempA B on a.id = b.id
```

It returns 3 rows from TempA as expected,  good so far.  Let's add a filter in query above

```
   select a.* 
     from TempA a 
left JOIN TempA B on a.id = b.id  
    where b.msg = 'aa'
```

It return no rows to me. I thought that since its a left join, i should still get 3 rows from TempA table. Am I wrong?

Comment: Note: all the example queries are self-joins. I think you mean for the second table to be "TempB". That would explain why the answers below aren't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are converting the left join to an inner join by including the `b.msg` filter in the `where` clause use.

```
select a.* from TempA a left JOIN TempB B on a.id = b.id and b.msg = 'aa'
```

(Conceptually) the Join Predicate happens, the non joining rows from A get added back in and will have a value of `NULL` for  `b.msg` then you exclude these rows again with the filter!

You might want to review Itzik Ben Gan's [Logical Query Processing Poster](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf)

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit how is it been converted to an inner join?

Comment: your where condition `b.msg='aa'` can never be true for any rows that were output by the join with all the `b` columns null because the `on` condition did not match; so the join is *effectively* acting as an inner join.

Comment: Think of it this way, the FROM clause, with all its joins, determines an initial data set. Then the WHERE clause filters stuff out. If you put the filter in the LEFT JOIN, you will get all rows from "A", along with whatever "B" records match the join condition. Try including b.msg in your Select. In your example, they will all be NULLs. Now move the condition to the WHERE clause. All the records with b.msg=NULL (because no match) get filtered out.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what's going on;

You have two tables.

```
TempA ID Msg
      -- ---
      1  a
      2  b
      3  c

TempB ID Msg
      -- ---
```

Now, when you do the join, the initial result looks like this:

```
Result a.ID a.Msg b.ID b.Msg
       ---- ----- ---- -----
       1    a     NULL NULL
       2    b     NULL NULL
       3    c     NULL NULL
```

When you filter that query with the `WHERE` clause, you're filtering out anything that doesn't have a `b.Msg` of `'aa'`. That would filter out **all** the records, because all of them have a `b.Msg` of `NULL`. Leaving you with this:

```
Result a.ID a.Msg b.ID b.Msg
       ---- ----- ---- -----
```

Then, you're only selecting the columns from `TempA` which makes this the final result:

```
Result a.ID a.Msg
       ---- -----
```

Comment: nice, but then the solution @Conrd provided should work too. How come that didn't work?

Comment: @imak: probably because you keep joining `TempA` with itself - `TempA` again, under the `B` alias..... you probably really want to join to `TempB B`....

Answer (score 2):

When using an OUTER JOIN, criteria provided in the `WHERE` clause is applied ***after*** the JOIN.  Because there are no rows where b.msg = 'aa', no rows will be returned.

When the criteria is specified in the `ON` clause, the criteria is applied ***before*** the JOIN, so references to `b` will only be affected.  In this example, `b` references will return NULL while the `a` references are unaffected.

Comment: is this rule of WHERE been applied after join is also true in case of INNER JOINs?

Comment: @imak: There's no difference when using INNER JOINs, only OUTER JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

I perfer Matin's solution but the other option  is

```
select a.* 
from 
    TempA a 
    left JOIN TempB B on a.id = b.id
where b.msg = 'aa' or b.msg is null
```

Comment: this doesn't give me any results either

Comment: @imak - Your original query had TempA where TempB should have been. This returns results for the DDL in your question `select a.* from TempA a left JOIN TempB b on a.ID = b.ID where b.Msg = 'aa' or b.Msg is null`

Comment: @imak: probably because you keep joining `TempA` with itself - `TempA` again, under the `B` alias..... you probably really want to join to `TempB B`....

Comment: @Martin. That's what I get for copying and pasting without looking too closely. I've updated it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you do the filtering.
I answered a similar question a few months ago. Check out my explanation about left joins there:

[What is the difference in these two queries as getting two different result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926969/what-is-the-difference-in-these-two-queries-as-getting-two-different-result-set/3927915#3927915)